# Differentiate response of Squid reverse proxy server and a web server behind the Squid

Tags: squid

When we do a GET method request on a browser that is configured to use a  proxy, can we tell from the response headers(Chrome Dev Tools) that the response came from a Squid proxy server and not the web server behind the squid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Responses generated by Squid will have the HTTP header:

```
 Server: squid
```

Responses that were simply delivered *through* the proxy should contain a Via header. But many proxy admin disable that header because so much supposedly HTTP software breaks when it is sent.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'll check the packets and compare them too.